# Pytorch cosine similarity NxN elements

Tags: python, pytorch

I have 128 vectors of embeddings

```
image.shape = torch.Size([128, 512])
text.shape = torch.Size([128, 512])
```

And I want to calculate the tensor containing the cosine similarity between all elements (i.e:

```
cosine.shape = torch.Size([128, 128])
```

Where the first row is the cosine similarity between the 1st image and all text (128), etc.

At the moment I'm only doing this, but the result is a one-dimension array containing only N cosine similarities.

```
cosine_similarity = torch.nn.CosineSimilarity()

cosine = cosine_similarity(image, text)
```

How can I do it? I tried to transpose text but didn't work

Answer (score 4):

The way pytorch computes cosine similarity internally is like this:

```
    def cos_sim(A, B, dim, eps=1e-08):
      numerator = torch.mul(A, B).sum(axis=dim, keepdims=True)
      A_l2 = torch.mul(A, A).sum(axis=dim, keepdims=True)
      B_l2 = torch.mul(B, B).sum(axis=dim, keepdims=True)
      denominator = torch.max(torch.sqrt(torch.mul(A_l2, B_l2)) torch.tensor(eps))
      return torch.div(numerator, denominator).squeeze()
```

In order to get NxN cosine similarity, you can instead use this function:

```
    def nxn_cos_sim(A, B, dim=1, eps=1e-8):
      numerator = A @ B.T
      A_l2 = torch.mul(A, A).sum(axis=dim)
      B_l2 = torch.mul(B, B).sum(axis=dim)
      denominator = torch.max(torch.sqrt(torch.outer(A_l2, B_l2)), torch.tensor(eps))
      return torch.div(numerator, denominator)
```

Ahmed's answer also works, but if the value for N is large you will face memory issues using it.

Edit 09.2023:
The way I do it in my code now is:

```
  def nxn_cos_sim(A, B, dim=1):
     a_norm = f.normalize(A, p=2, dim=dim)
     b_norm = f.normalize(B, p=2, dim=dim)
     return torch.mm(a_norm, b_norm.transpose(0, 1))
```

Comment: I think you mean `torch.mul(A_l2, B_l2)` instead of `torch.outer(A_l2, B_l2)` in your second approach

Comment: with batch dimension, I would suggest:

`def nxn_cos_sim(A, B, dim=-1, eps=1e-8):
  numerator = torch.bmm(A, torch.permute(B, (0, 2, 1)))
  A_l2 = torch.mul(A, A).sum(axis=dim)
  B_l2 = torch.mul(B, B).sum(axis=dim)
  denominator = torch.max(torch.sqrt(torch.mul(A_l2, B_l2)), torch.tensor(eps))
  return torch.div(numerator, denominator.unsqueeze(-1))`

Answer (score 3):

**A simpler and elegant solution:**

```
import torch.nn.functional as F

similarity_matrix = F.cosine_similarity(image.unsqueeze(0), text.unsqueeze(1), dim=2)
```

`similarity_matrix` has the shape 128x128.

**Explanation:**

As explained in its [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity.html#torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity), `F.cosine_similarity(x1, x2, dim)` returns the cosine similarity between `x1` and `x2` along `dim`, as long as `x1`and `x2` can be broadcasted to a common shape.

Your original tensors `image` and `text` have the shape 128x512 each, so after applying the `F.cosine_similarity` function on `dim=1`, you get as output a one-dimensional tensor of size 128.

To get an output of shape 128x128, you must make `image` and `text` broadcastable to that shape. In other words, you must reshape `image` to 1x128x512 and `text` to 128x1x512.

**Reference:**

[Item 6 on this blog post](https://zablo.net/blog/post/pytorch-13-features-you-should-know/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
repeated_image = image.repeat_interleave(128, dim=0)
repeated_text = text.repeat(128, 1)

distances = torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity(repeated_image, repeated_text, dim=1)
distances = distances.reshape(128, 128)
```

Explanation:
In order to do the computations faster, it is better to copy the data and then use the GPU to do the steps in parallel, rather than for-loop over all possible pairs. The first two lines are copying the data in an appropriate way:

`repeat_interleave` will copy each element of the tensor (which is a 512-dimensional image) along dim=0, which will create a (128*128, 512) tensor whose first 128 elements belong to the first image, and so on.

`repeat` will repeat the entire tensor 128 times along the 0-th dimension, again creating a (128*128, 512) tensor, where the first element belongs to the first text, the second element belongs to the second text, and so on (the 129-th element belongs to the first text.)

We then compute all pairwise distances using the `cosine_similarity` function, and then reshape to get them into the appropriate shape.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the answer of Mattia, I suggest to write for batched cosine similarity:

```
def nxn_cos_sim(A, B, dim=-1, eps=1e-8):
  numerator = torch.bmm(A, torch.permute(B, (0, 2, 1)))
  A_l2 = torch.mul(A, A).sum(axis=dim)
  B_l2 = torch.mul(B, B).sum(axis=dim)
  denominator = torch.max(torch.sqrt(torch.mul(A_l2, B_l2)), torch.tensor(eps))
  return torch.div(numerator, denominator.unsqueeze(-1))
```